# No sound output with Ubuntu 13.10 After changing Drivers

Tags: drivers, sound, 13.10, ati

I have previously get my sound to be working with this version after I follow the article [here](http://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/).

But just after I change the driver at Software and updates-> Additional Drivers to a proprietary drivers, the sound driver stop working. The problem persists even after I revert it back to the one which Ubuntu recommend (open source, tested). I tried to follow some of the help instructions given in other threads but they are not helpful.

The driver which I change is Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]: Juniper XT [Radeon HD5770]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a answer that has been tried and it solves my problem. Hopefully it will be an useful reference for other. [The answer originate from here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2200794).

> Open a terminal window via cntrl/alt/F!
>
> log in with your normal userid and normal password - the password is
>   not echoed to the screen
>
> type:
>
> cd /etc/default
>
> sudo cp grub grub-original < press enter > This creates a copy of the
>   file before you modify it
>
> sudo gedit grub < press enter>
>
> This will start up the editor and open the grub file for editing. You
>   want to look for a line like this:
>
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
>
> and change it to look like this:
>
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.audio=1"
>
> Then click on save, wait for it to save, then exit the editor to
>   return back to the terminal window.
>
> Type:
>
> sudo update-grub < press enter >
>
> sudo shutdown -r now < press enter >
>
> These last 2 steps will regenerate a file used at boot time, then
>   shutdown with a reboot (-r) so your PC will reboot.
>
> After reboot, click on the sound icon on the top bar, click on "Sound
>   Settings", and hopefully you will see the option now for HDMI sound
>   output. You'll have to click on it to make it the default, then just
>   close out of it.
>
> Try something now to see if the sound is active via HDMI now.